# Why two separate processes can bind() to the same TCP port, but can't listen simultaneously?

Tags: linux, sockets

A simple C code file looks like this:

```
fd = socket(...)
set_reuseaddr(...)
bind(fd, 6666,...)
```

This code can be run by two separate processes in one machine (Linux). But when I add `listen()` into code like this:

```
fd = socket(...)
set_reuseaddr(...)
bind(fd, 6666,...)
listen(fd)
```

The second process calls `bind()` with failure.

First, I have not found the use for two separate processes that `bind()` to the same port only and not call `listen()`.

So I'm confused, why the implementation can't just return a failure when one process tries to bind an existing port, and why it delays to the `listen()`?

Answer (score 5):

This behaviour is addressed in the manual page, quote:

```
   SO_REUSEADDR
          Indicates that the rules used in validating addresses supplied
          in a bind(2) call should allow reuse of local addresses.  For
          AF_INET sockets this means that a socket may bind, except when
          there is an active listening socket bound to the address.
          When the listening socket is bound to INADDR_ANY with a spe‐
          cific port then it is not possible to bind to this port for
          any local address.  Argument is an integer boolean flag.
```

So, it might be clear from the quote that binding will work unless there is an active *listening* socket already bound to the address.

Also, you could probably consider using **SO_REUSEPORT** to redistribute **accept()** calls between worker processes. That said, usage for this might deserve dedicated discussion.